# Find deb file of sublime text build 3132

Tags: sublimetext3, apt

After build 3132 sublime text page no more offers download links for the deb installation files.Is there any way to find the deb file links without installing them from apt?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a URL that will always download the deb file of the latest build, it is https://download.sublimetext.com/latest/dev/linux/x64/deb.

Otherwise, for a specific build, you need to replace the `3133` in this link to the build number you want to download:

https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime-text_build-3133_amd64.deb

Comment: the top link refers to the latest dev build.  Dev builds are only available for licensed users, so you if you need the latest stable, you can use https://download.sublimetext.com/latest/stable/linux/x64/deb